# C# Lambda to filter list based on existence on another list

Tags: c#, lambda

**List A**: 3,5,5,5,7,9
**List B**: 3,5

Both of the list are the same type and those values are from a field `ID`. My objective is to construct a forloop that will return me `7,9` because `7,9` is not existed in **List B**.

I've tried the following but no luck:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach(var item in ListA.Where(x=>ListB.Any(b=>x.ID != b.ID)))
{
    counter++;
    //Here I should perform operation with item that having ID 7 and 9
}
```

**Updates:**
Using a `except` method in the above case, `counter` will still return me `4` simply because each of the `5` in **ListA** are different object eventhou they are sharing the same ID. My ultimate objective is to have the `counter` as `2` irregardless whether the object is the same or not. As long as the `ID` of object in **ListA** is `3` or `5`, I would wanna exclude it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be "ALL", or "Not Any"

```
foreach(var item in ListA.Where(x=>ListB.All(b=>x.ID != b.ID)))
{
    //Here I should perform operation with item that having ID 7 and 9
}
```

update:

As you actually want to have distinct result from A except B, so, you can do either:

```
foreach(var item in ListA.GroupBy(m=>m.ID).Where(x=>ListB.All(b=>b.ID != x.Key)))
{
    counter ++;
    Debug.writeline(item.Key);
}
```

or

```
foreach(var id in ListA.Select(x=>x.ID).Distinct().Except(ListB.Select(y=>y.ID)))
{
    counter++;
}
```

note: all untested - i have no compiler with me for the moment.

Comment: Please help take a look at my updated question. Sorry for the lack of information given earlier.

Comment: i think the solution i give above (using All) should yield what you wanted to achieve, right? (even though i have not tested it...)

Comment: or you can use: foreach(var item in ListA.Where(x=>!ListB.Any(b=>x.ID == b.ID)))

Comment: sorry did not look at your update carefully - actually you want distinct output, see my update above.

Comment: The correct answer is using the combination of `Distinct` and `Except`. For your `GroupBy` way, it's not achieving objective. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `Except` extension mtehod

```
foreach (var item in ListA.Except(ListB)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Please help take a look at my updated question. Sorry for the lack of information given earlier.

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep even if `ListA` has duplicate elements,`Except` method should work.Are you sure you try it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Change your query like this:

```
foreach(var item in ListA.Where(x=> !ListB.Any(b => x.ID == b.ID)))
```

And it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
List<int> listA=new List<int>(new[]{ 3,5,7,9});
List<int> listB=new List<int>(new[]{ 3,5});

var items=(from a in listA
           select a).Except(from b in listB
           select b);

foreach(var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ll);
}
```

**Output:**

```
7  
9
```

Comment: query syntax seems _highly_ unnecessary here :)

Comment: @Selman22: yes dear i realized it now and frankly speaking i don;t have idea about lambda expressions, is it easy to learn? if you can, please give me some references.

Comment: Here is the [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), though you don't need to use lambda statements here :) just `ListA.Except(listB)` should be sufficient

Comment: @Selman22: Thanks Dear :) , yes you are right `@JaredPar` has the same answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Except method can be used when both List are of same type. 
If Type is different. We can use like this.

var outPut = _employees.Where(i => _employeeExtensions.Any(j => i.EmpId == j.EmpId));

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the items in a list where the items' `ID`s are different:

Example that I put together in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Person> a = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person { ID = 1 },
        new Person { ID = 2 },
        new Person { ID = 3 },
    };

    List<Person> b = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person { ID = 1 },
    };

    var c = a.Where(x => b.Any(bprime => bprime.ID != x.ID));

    foreach(var item in c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ID);
    }
}

class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

2

3

This works similar to the `Except` method but this will check the elements' properties.